# "Main class could not be found or loaded"

Tags: java

I made a jar file but when I test it I get a message that the *Main class could not be found or loaded*.

I have this code:

```
C:\trafficProject\src>echo Main-Class: Main >manifest.txt     

C:\trafficProject\src>jar cvfm trafficProject.jar manifest.txt     
added manifest

C:\trafficProject\src>java -jar trafficProject.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you sure your main class is actually called Main and not TrafficProject or something? Should be the name of the class that contains your declaration for main.

Comment: Show the output from `jar tf trafficProject.jar`

Answer (score 2):

The MANIFEST.MF should be in a subdirectory META-INF. Case-sensitive, all capitals!

Read the documentation, search in the internet. To overcome starter's problems.

Answer (score 0):

the 'c' option means create (a new empty jar file). You need to add classes to the new jar file, i.e. add .class files in the argument list after manifest.txt. Or if you want to just update an existing jar file, use 'u' instead of 'c'.